# JPA @ManyToOne does not working

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, many-to-one

I can't understand where I'm going wrong when saving a List within and JPA Entity.
I have a super class Person. Client class extends Person. Client class has a list of Phone entities as @OneToMany (Bidirection) as code shown below. Whenever a Client entity is persisted with that phone list, all phones in list are saved as well. However, in Phone Table there are no client id recorded.

```
@Entity@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)@DiscriminatorColum(name="type")
public abstract class Person implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="PERSON_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name="PERSON_SEQ",sequenceName="PERSON_SEQ", allocationSize=1,initialValue=1000) 
private Long id;

private String name;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}}
```

Client.class

public class Client extends Person implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


private String foo;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="owner")
private List<Phone> phones;

public List<Phone> getPhones() {
    return phones;
}


public void setPhones(List<Phone> phones) {
    this.phones = phones;
}


public String getFoo() {
    return foo;
}


public void setFoo(String foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}
```

}

Phone class

public class Phone implements Serializable {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long idPhone;

private String number;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) @JoinColumn(name="id")
private Person owner;

public Long getIdPhone() {
    return idPhone;
}

public void setIdPhone(Long idPhone) {
    this.idPhone = idPhone;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public Person getOwner() {
    return owner;
}

public void setOwner(Person owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}
```

}

ClientController class

```
@Named(value = "clientController")
```

@ViewScoped
public class ClientController extends BaseController implements Serializable {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private ClientService service;

@Inject
private Client client;


@Inject 
private Employee employee;

@Inject 
private Phone phone;


public void save(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println(" Saving in Controller");

    try {

        client = new Client();
        employee = new Employee();
        Phone p1 = new Phone();
        p1.setNumber("99998888");
        Phone p2 = new Phone();
        p2.setNumber("88887777");
        List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<Phone>();
        phones.add(p1);
        phones.add(p2);
        client.setName("Novembro" );
        client.setPhones(phones);
        employee.setPhones(phones);

        client.setFoo("foo value" );
        employee.setBar("bar value");

        service.saveOrUpdate(client);

        //client = new Client();
        addMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cliente registrado com sucesso");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        addMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Tente mais tarde");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Client Service class

```
public class ClientService implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private ClientDAO dao;


public Client saveOrUpdate(Client client) {
    System.out.println(" Saving in Service");


        return dao.save(client);


}
```

}

DAO save method

```
public T save(T entity) {
    beginTransaction();
    em.persist(entity);
    em.flush();
    commitAndCloseTransaction();
    return entity;
}
```

I can't understand why it is not working as expected. I mean, save phones entities with ID from Client who owns the phones.

Database Postgresql 9.6
EclipseLink 2.6.0
JPA 2.1

All classes have @Entity and @Discrimator annotations

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="C")

@Entity
@Table(name="PHONE")

Comment: You've added the phone to the client's list of phones, but in the mapping you've stated it is 'mappedby' the phone.client mapping, making it bidirectional and indicating the foreign key is controled by the phone.client reference.  Leaving this as null in your model leaves the foreign key as null in the database.  Set both to keep your model in synch with the database to avoid issues.

Comment: It's working now. Thanks, Chris.